# command line in AppleScript

Tags: applescript, command-line

I want to create an AppleScript app with this perfectly working (bash) command:

```
cd /Volumes/MEDIAS/WORK/CONVERSION_VIDEO/PROXY_720P/INPUT/; for f in *.mov *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -vcodec prores -profile:v 0 -s 1280x720 /Volumes/MEDIAS/WORK/CONVERSION_VIDEO/PROXY_720P/OUTPUT/"${f%.*}_PROXY_720P.mov" && rm "$f"; done
```

but I get errors with the variable "$f".

How can I launch it through AppleScript?

Comment: Welcome to AskDifferent!  Consider rewriting your question so that it sticks to one topic - right now you have two - how to run a bash command in AppleScript and a problem with the variable expansion of `f`.  What error are you getting and what specifically would you like to know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shell *scripts/commands* in AppleScript are handled with the `do shell script` *command*, which executes a *shell script* using the `sh` *shell*. In the short form of:

```
do shell script "..."
```

Where `...` is the *shell script* to execute.

See [AppleScript Language Guide `do shell script` Commands Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW40) and [Technical Note TN2065 `do shell script` in AppleScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2065/_index.html), for additional details.

What you need to do, is escape the double-quotes with a backslash, e.g. `\"$f\"` and elsewhere as necessary.

I've tested your *command*, wrapped in a `do shell script` *command*, with the necessary escaping as shown in the *command* below and it worked without issue.

```
do shell script "cd /Volumes/MEDIAS/WORK/CONVERSION_VIDEO/PROXY_720P/INPUT/; for f in *.mov *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i \"$f\" -vcodec prores -profile:v 0 -s 1280x720 /Volumes/MEDIAS/WORK/CONVERSION_VIDEO/PROXY_720P/OUTPUT/\"${‌​f%.*}_PROXY_720P.mov‌​\" && rm \"$f\"; done"
```

**Note:** Because the `do shell script` *command* uses the `sh` *shell*, if the `ffmpeg` executable is not in the `PATH` passed to the *shell*, which is `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`, you'll need to include the fully qualified pathname to the `ffmpeg` executable for your *command* to work in AppleScript.

Answer (score -1):

The direct parameter of the do shell script command is a string containing the shell code you want to execute, as demonstrated in Listing 39-1, which simply lists a directory.

APPLESCRIPT

Open in Script Editor
Listing 39-1AppleScript: Executing a simple shell command that lists the contents of a directory

```
do shell script "ls /Applications/"
(*
--> Result:
"App Store.app
Automator.app
Calculator.app
Calendar.app
..."
*)
```